# websocket object is not connecting the socket in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, sockets, websocket

Hy, I'm trying to connect WebSocket in react-native but it's not connected on the first attempt. I have two screen users and a chat screen. On the users screen when I click on the user it navigates to chat screen.

According to the documentation of WebSocket

> In order to communicate using the WebSocket protocol, you need to create a WebSocket object; this will automatically attempt to open the connection to the server.
> I created the object like this:

```
  const client = new W3CWebSocket(
    'ws://url:port/api/ws/chat/1/' + logID + '/',
  );
```

and complete look like this

```
  const client = new W3CWebSocket(
    'ws://url:port/api/ws/chat/1/' + logID + '/',
  );
  
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
        getID()

        client.onopen = () => {
            console.log('WebSocket Client Connected');
        };
        client.onmessage=(message)=>{
            const dataFromServer = JSON.parse(message.data);
            console.log('got reply! ', dataFromServer);
            if(dataFromServer){
                setMessages(messages => [
                    ...messages,
                    {msg: dataFromServer.type, sender: dataFromServer.sender},
                  ]);
            }
        }
      scrollHandler();
      return () => {
      scrollHandler();
      client.close()
      };
    }, []),
  );
```

But it does not connect to the WebSocket, but when I do some changes on my code or say when I save the code file after opening the chat screen, it is connected. That's means when I navigate the screens from user->chat it does not connect but on coming to the chat screen I go back to vscode and code of chat screen just press ctrl+s it connects the socket. I also try it inside the useEffect or useFocusEffect but it still behaves the same.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: @prog-fh yes it is correct in real code.

Comment: Any luck with a solution to this? Running into the same problem.

Comment: did u fixed this issue?